# When reading CSV in R, how do you keep the time and date format the same?

Tags: r, csv, format, readr

My CSV looks as follows [image: like this]

But when I read it in R, it changes the format for Date and Time(most important issue).
[image: This]

Here is my simple code that I used to read the csv

```
library(readr)
dat1<- read_csv("2010.csv")
```

How can I make it so that the format for date and time doesn't change and looks like the first picture?

Comment: Can you put `str(dat1)` or even better `dput(dat1)` in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
dat1 <- read.table("2010.csv", sep = ",", header = T)
```

**If this answer goes wrong**, then:

First check exactly what's in your `.csv` by opening it with `text` or some `code editors` instead of `Excel` or something like that. The problem I think maybe is that some APP like `MS Excel`, it will do some auto format converting in preview mode, so what you saw may be not what's really in your file.

For example: `2015-1-1` in `.csv` when open with `Excel`, it becomes `2015/1/1`

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed the problem.